# Grabbing parts of a date in a different timezone with moment

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

This may be an odd question, but I have a moment date which I will later need to grab parts of it for different usages. For example, I grab the day and display doing `date.date()` from `moment`.

All that is find and dandy, but the issue is timezones are relevant to this.
So I have my moment object, which is created from the string:

```
const properDate = moment.tz(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.SSS', 'America/New_York')
```

From my understanding, for me to get the proper timezone time, I would do

```
properDate.format()
```

But this will convert it to a string. And I would like to be able to fetch the time and days on the correct timezone. So basically, when I do `properDate.hours()` I will get it in UTC's time, but I want it in `America/New_York`.

Say for example the date string I want to put in is `2018-12-31 02:00:00.000 +00:00`

When I run it through the above code, and then do `properDate.hours()` I am going to get `2`, but I would like to get it in the New York timezone, which would be `21`, and would also be the previous day if I want to get the date.

I suppose a way around this would be to convert it to a date object using `new Date` and setting each one manually, perhaps? Something like this:

```
const dateWithTimezoneObject = new Date(properDate.year(), properDate.month(), properDate.date(), properDate.hours(), properDate.minutes())
```

But that sounds like a bit of a mess and I was wondering if there is a better way of getting this done, possibly through moment.

So, is there a way for me to get the parts of the moment object in the proper timezone time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
var m = moment("2018-12-31 02:00:00.000 +00:00","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z")
           .tz('America/New_York');

m.hours() //=> 21
```

A few things:

- Note the input format provided is case sensitive and needs to match the input string.  In your question, you had `hh` instead of `HH`, and also didn't provide the `Z` for the time zone offset.
- There are *two* different flavors of the `tz` function.  `moment.tz()` is for constructing a moment where the input value is in terms of that time zone.  `moment().tz()` is for converting a moment to a different time zone.
- Though I just used `moment` in my example above, you could use `moment.tz`, `moment.utc` or `moment.parseZone` and the effect would be the same, but only because you included the offset `+00:00` in the input string.  If you don't actually have that offset, then you'd want to use `moment.utc`, like this:

  ```
  var m = moment.utc("2018-12-31 02:00:00.000","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS")
                .tz('America/New_York');
  ```
- Regarding your proposed solution, that would be creating a `Date` object representing a different point in time. In general, once you are using Moment you should avoid using the `Date` object if you can use a Moment function instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  Test
  <script src="moment.js"></script>
  <script src="moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
  <script>
    const date = '2018-12-31 02:00:00.000 +00:00' 
    const new_york = moment(date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS Z')
      .tz('America/New_York')
    document.body.textContent = 
      `day: ${new_york.dates()} hour: ${new_york.hours()}`
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/